# How to add small circle in the bottom boarder using CSS with the line border

Tags: html, css

I would like to add a small circle under menu item using CSS like the picture below:

[image: Menu One]

and here what I did so far:

[image: Menu Two]

And this is the HTML:

```
<ul>
 <li class="nav-item">
   <a href="#" class="active">VISION</a>
 </li>
 <li class="nav-item">
   <a href="#">CULTURE</a>
 </li>
 <li class="nav-item">
   <a href="#">SPACE</a>
 </li>
 <li class="nav-item">
   <a href="#">CONTACT US</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

here is the "nav-item" CSS:

```
.nav-item {
 font-family:"Geometria-Light";
 font-size: 12px;
 border-bottom: .2px solid #C29B4C;
 color:#FFFFFF!important;
}
```

and here is the "active" CSS:

```
.active{
 border-bottom: .2px solid #C29B4C;
 color:#C29B4C !important;
}
```

Can anyone explain to me how can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you post your existing HTML and CSS ?

Comment: Sure, I edited my question.

Comment: @IhabShoully you want it when the nav bar is hovered?

Comment: Yes, when hoverd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
}

.nav-item {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-bottom: .2px solid #C29B4C;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav-link {
  font-family: "Geometria-Light";
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.item-active {
  position: relative;
}

.item-active a {
  color: #C29B4C !important;
}

.item-active:before {
  content: '';
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  background-color: #C29B4C;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -4px;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">it0</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item item-active">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link ">VISION</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">it2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your nav-item with .dot class

```
<li class="nav-item">
 <a href="#" class="nav-link item-active">VISION</a>
 <span class="dot"></span>
</li>
```

here is .class css code

```
.item-active .dot {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: #C29B4C;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
}
```

i think it will be work for you

Comment: I like your idea, it's nice, but I prefer to use "Quetzalcoatl" answer because of the "item-active" selector will be changed when clicked.